# Sorting by arbitrary lambda

Tags: python, sorting

How can I sort a list by a key described by an arbitrary function?  For example, if I have:

```
mylist = [["quux", 1, "a"], ["bar", 0, "b"]]
```

I'd like to sort "mylist" by the second element of each member, e.g.

```
sort(mylist, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

how can I do this?

Comment: What was the issue when you tried the code you provide?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You basically have it already:

```
>>> mylist = [["quux", 1, "a"], ["bar", 0, "b"]]
>>> mylist.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> print mylist
```

gives:

```
[['bar', 0, 'b'], ['quux', 1, 'a']]
```

That will sort mylist in place.

[this para edited thanks to @Daniel's correction.]  `sorted` will return a new list that is sorted rather than actually changing the input, as described in http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/.

Answer (score 10):

You have two options, very close to what you described, actually:

```
mylist.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]) # In place sort
new_list = sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Answer (score 10):

This is such a common need that support for it has been added to the standard library, in the form of [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter
mylist = [["quux", 1, "a"], ["bar", 0, "b"]]
mylist.sort(key=itemgetter(1)) # or sorted(mylist, key=...)
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer is to use "sorted", i.e.

```
sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: I had the parameters backwards.  Seems inconsistent that e.g. map/filter/reduce take the lambda first parameter and list second parameter but sorted the reverse.

Answer (score 5):

Sort and itemgetter is the fastest.

```
>>> import operator
>>> import timeit

>>> mylist = [["quux", 1, "a"], ["bar", 0, "b"]]
>>> t1 = timeit.Timer(lambda: mylist.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]))
>>> t1.timeit()
1.6330803055632404

>>> t2 = timeit.Timer(lambda: mylist.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
>>> t2.timeit()
1.3985503043467773

>>> t3 = timeit.Timer(lambda: sorted(mylist, key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
>>> t3.timeit()
2.6329514733833292

>>> t4 = timeit.Timer(lambda: sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: x[1]))
>>> t4.timeit()
2.9197154810598533
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution of your question is:
`sorted_list = sorted(mylist, key=lambda value:value[1])`

Solution for dictionary of list is:

```
mylist = [{'name':'kk', 'age':21},{'name':'bk', 'age':21}]

sorted_list = sorted(mylist, key=lambda k: k['key_name'])
```