# Python list of list sorting but with respect to specific elements

Tags: python-3.x

I am having list of list and when i am using sort() then it is sorting my list according to first element. What should i do to sort with respect to other elements in python.
[Snapshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWGKB.png)

```
sheetmarks=[]
for _ in range(int(input())):
sheetmarks.append([input(),float(input())])
sheetmarks.sort()
print(sheetmarks)
```

Output::::[['Akriti', 41.0], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Harry', 37.21], ['Harsh', 39.0], ['Tina', 37.2]]

But i would like to sort this list of list according to number not by name. I am new at programming and python. Need some suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sorting-by-arbitrary-lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216398/sorting-by-arbitrary-lambda)

Comment: I got it now sir. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
output.sort(lambda element: element[1])
```

Will sort by second element.

```
>>> output
[['Tina', 37.2], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Harry', 37.21], ['Harsh', 39.0], ['Akriti', 41.0]]
```